# How to extend UWP app's window into multiple screen

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to make UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application with visual C# and xaml which is displayed into multiple screen with full screen mode.

So, at first I added the code to enter into full screen mode in `App.xaml.cs` like below.

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

I'm not sure how to extend the window into multiple screen.
I use two 4K displays but the application is displayed in one screen with full screen mode.

The resolution of 1 display is `3840*2160`, so the application should be displayed in the size of `3840*4320` with full screen mode.

The OS presentation setting of multiple screen is "Extend".

Anybody know how to extend application window?

The application target of windows is "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update 16299"

Comment: It looks like an OS configuration property, instead of uwp config

Comment: Thank you @Ferus7, but the configuration property of display is Extend, and I want my program to display in the resolution of `3840*4320` (the double size of two 4K display) in full screen mode.

Comment: If you have a good graphic card, maybe you should configure it to run in **mosaic mode**

Comment: Yes @Ferus7, if we use GPU mosaic mode, we can treat two displays as 1 display. But if there is some way to do without GPU's config, I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does **not** support natively **mosaic mode**.

You can connect **n** number of monitors, but you still only will be able to configure them with **extend** functionality.

Given that multiple displays requires a good and/or powerful multiple graphic cards.

**Third party** manufacturers like Nvidia, developed a set of **drivers** that can support this functionality, so, the way to go is not native to Microsoft, there is not support on the .NET framework for this.